# Force Windows or IE8 to open certain URLs in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

Rightly or wrongly we have certain applications which have been developed for IE8 and as such we use it as our primary browser.

However certain users are needing HTML5 compliant browsers for certain websites meaning we've got disparate installs of Firefox and Chrome.

I'm part way through Thinapping Chrome or I might revert to a portable install, but I'd like to know if anyone has any ideas about how to make IE redirect certain URLs to a different browser?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Websites or even WebApps should be designed to work in all major browsers. You could put a message in the website with your 'preferred' browser and a link. Do your users not know how to open websites up in different browsers?

Answer (score 3):

Stop punishing your users by keeping them on ancient versions of IE. =)  Your salvation (assuming your machines are Windows 7 or later) is in IE 11 and it's called [Enterprise Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687.aspx).  From the page:

> Enterprise Mode, a compatibility mode that runs on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 Update and Windows 7 devices, lets websites render using a modified browser configuration that’s designed to emulate Internet Explorer 8, avoiding the common compatibility problems associated with web apps written and tested on older versions of Internet Explorer.

Basically you can configure via group policy the list of sites that should render using IE 8 emulation and you can also enable your users to manually turn on the emulation for the sites you missed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class for a specific protocol and then use that protocol in your link.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CUSTPROT]
@="\"URL:CUSTPROT Protocol\""
"DefaultIcon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe,1\""
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CUSTPROT\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" \"http://yourURL.com""
```

Then use `custprot:http` as your link and when you click in IE, it should open "http://yourURL.com" in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins for browsers which allow them to open certain URL's in another browser.

E.g. chrome is capable of opening specific URL's using IE's engine with the [IE TAB](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en) plugin. There should be plugins for other browsers as well.